# How to move query from Redshift to Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, presto

```
Case when source='a' then '\'qwerty Rs\' + {%raw%}{#difference}{%endraw%} + \' xyz\'' 
when source='b' then '\'qwerty Rs \' + {%raw%}{#difference}{%endraw%} + \' qwerty\''
when source='c' then '\'qwerty Rs \' + {%raw%}{#difference}{%endraw%} + \' qwerty\'' 
when source='d' then '\'qwerty Rs \' + {%raw%}{#difference}{%endraw%} + \' qwerty\'' 
else null end as insight_text
```

The above query block is in Redshift SQL, and I need to convert this to Presto SQL.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What Presto implementation are you using? The reference docs for the CASE statement is [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#case)

Comment: Are you using athena?